# See what a user did with date/time?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to see what a specific linux user on my system did, and I looked at bash_history, but it doesn't have any dates.

Is there a method I can look at that would give me dates/time?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, there is (per default) no definite log that associate date/time with each command launched by an user.

However you can try to guess the actions an user did by tallying informations from the command `last` (which will give you the dates and time when the users logged on the system) with the logs you'll find in `/var/log` such as syslog.

With chance the command issued some log output in one of the different logs available.

Additionally you can check dates and time of creation/modification of files that you suspect having been affected by the commands you saw in the bash_history, this could give you some more hints on what happened.

Answer (score 0):

This would *not* passively update .bash_history but it would make this task easier in the future.

History timestamps can be done by exporting a variable called `HISTTIMEFORMAT` you would set it to the format that you would like the timestamp to look like using strftime formatting found by running the command `man strftime` or [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime)

Example:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T: "
```

I would suggest putting this in ~/.bashrc